# VBA Excel sort function

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to come up with a way to sort my Excel-Table

The problem: I need to sort something like this

```css
Col1 Col2

ABC123 XYZ
ABC123 XYZ
ABC123 XYZ
ABC123 XYZ
ABC123 KLJ
ABC123 KLJ
ABC123 KLJ
ABC123 KLJ
ABC123 III
ABC123 III
ABC123 III
DEF456 uuu
DEF456 LKK
DEF456 LKK
DEF456 WWW
DEF456 WWW
ZZZ KLMNOP
ZZZ KLMNOP
ZZZ KLMNOP
ZZZ KLMNOP
ZZZ jjj
ZZZ jjj
```

And this is the output:

```html
1 ABC123 1 XYZ 4 
  2 KLJ 4
  3 III 3
2 DEF456 1 uuu 1
  2 LKK 2
  3 WWW 2
3 ZZZ 1 KLMNOP 4
  2 jjj 2
```

Comment: i don't know what should i do. Collection? Or other way

Comment: I'm trying to write vba code. I can't find sort algorithm for my problem

Comment: You could store them as a 2 dimensional array. Then do a count of how many times an item is repeated. That would be one way to do it. Or you could do a count of how many times a value in column A appears. Then do a count if against the values from column B from the range that you have gotten from the count of the values from column A.

Comment: Thank you for your attention , Sam! Can you write a little VBA code?

Comment: This would be more of a thing you need to look into yourself. This site is to help people just not just give the answers. Since you said you  are new to vba I would start with some tutorials

Comment: Okay, i'm not a "new" in VBA. My english just bad so i copy/paste the "Hello Guys" text from other user. Im never worked with arrays and other container-like tools. I know  sql, but in VBA cant find "distinct" :) .

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table - you'll get your solution and more from that

Comment: oh mother of god, i did not know about the availability of the pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Tom, use pivot table:

[image: insert pivot table] [image: prompt]

result (after adding fields as rows and taking the count on value region):

[image: Resulting]

Answer (score 0):

```html
Private Sub a()

Dim toAdd As Boolean, uniqueNumbers As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, z As Integer
z = 1
Cells(1, 3).Value = z
Cells(1, 4).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
uniqueNumbers = 1
toAdd = True

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To uniqueNumbers
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value Then
            toAdd = False
        End If
    Next j
    
    If toAdd = True Then
        z = z + 1
        Cells(uniqueNumbers, 3).Value = z
        Cells(uniqueNumbers, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        uniqueNumbers = uniqueNumbers '+ 1
    End If
    toAdd = True

    uniqueNumbers = uniqueNumbers + 1
    
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub b()

Dim toAdd As Boolean, uniqueNumbers As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, z As Integer, s As Integer, a As String, k As Integer

z = 1
j = 1
s = 1
k = 1

a = Cells(1, 4).Value
Cells(1, 5).Value = z
Cells(1, 6).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value
uniqueNumbers = 1
toAdd = True

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = k To uniqueNumbers
    'If j = 2800 Then Stop
        'If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 6).Value And a = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 6).Value And a = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            toAdd = False
        End If
    Next j
    
    If toAdd = True Then
          
        If Cells(uniqueNumbers, 4).Value = "" Then
            z = z + 1
            Cells(uniqueNumbers, 5).Value = z
        Else
            a = Cells(i, 4).Value
            k = i
            z = 1
            Cells(uniqueNumbers, 5).Value = z
        End If
        
        Cells(uniqueNumbers - s + 1, 7).Value = s - 1
        
        Cells(uniqueNumbers, 6).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        uniqueNumbers = uniqueNumbers '+ 1
        s = 1
    End If
    toAdd = True

    uniqueNumbers = uniqueNumbers + 1
    s = s + 1
    If i = 666 Then Stop
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution i use all the time is to automatically insert a Pivot. Assuming that you have the above mentioned data in A&B Columns of Sheet1, following code might help.

```
Sub InsertPivot()
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R23C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R30C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(30, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Col1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField     ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Col2"), "Count of Col2", xlCount
    'Range("B34").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Col2")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
End Sub
```